# CSRF and ValidateAntiForgeryToken in ASP.Net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I just implemented an example using ASP.NET MVC which use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute to prevent a CSRF attack.

For validating it, I craft the HTML pieces needed to make the same post request from another application. Basically, if I add the hidden field with the token encrypted value to this third-party application I get a successful post request.So I don't find any sense in [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] if I can see the hidden value just by inspecting the html source underlying the original form. Could someone give me an idea about what the real sense of it?

On the other hand, base on the results of my previous example, I wonder if Could a malicious user with a valid credentials on the application get his own token and use it for making a post request on behalf of other user, and execute a CSRF attack, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone give me an idea about what the real sense of it?

Nobody can read the token apart from the would-be victim of a CSRF attack. The [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents another site from reading the token from the user's session. There is no need to add anything else to the token, as long as the token is generated in a secure fashion and is unique to the browser session.

> On the other hand, base on the results of my previous example, I
>   wonder if Could a malicious user with a valid credentials on the
>   application get his own token and use it for making a post request on
>   behalf of other user, and execute a CSRF attack, ?

The token should be unique per user session. If Bob sets up a CSRF attack on `evil.example.com` and gets Alice to visit his site at the same time she is logged into `bank.example.org` and sends his own anti-CSRF token, the application should reject that token because it does not match Alice's session.

(It should also log this as a security event.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible the way you performed. But you can extend the protection by extending current implementation of Anti-forgery Token by adding other hidden/encrypted fields which consists agent information.

Following example let you know how to create custom AntiForgery Token

http://techbrij.com/angularjs-antiforgerytoken-asp-net-mvc